# CI for conditional probabilities

Tags: confidence-interval, conditional-probability

I am searching for some information about confidence intervals for conditional probabilities

I thought about treating them as normal probabilities with the formula

$$P(Y=i|x=t) \pm z \left(\frac{ \mathrm{Var}(P(Y=i))}{n} \right)^{1/2}$$

with $n$ the sample size of observations $t$. But is this valid?

Comment: Shouldn't the -1 be a 1/2?  You want the square root of that quantity.

Comment: If the conditional distribution $Y|x=t$ is Normal then the above equation will work.

Comment: P(Y=i) looks like a constant to me. In what sense does it have a variance?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem to simply calculate the distribution of $Y|x=t$ and if it is a recognizable distribution then it should not be to hard to figure out what its corresponding confidence interval is.  Otherwise you can just appeal to the definition of a confidence interval, i.e., "Let $Y|X$ be a random sample from a probability distribution with statistical parameters $\theta$, which is a quantity to be estimated, and $\phi$, representing quantities that are not of immediate interest. A confidence interval for the parameter $\theta$, with confidence level or confidence coefficient $\gamma$, is an interval with random endpoints $(u(Y|x), v(Y|X))$, determined by the pair of random variables $u(X)$ and $v(X)$, with the property:

$$    {\Pr}_{\theta,\varphi}(u(Y|X)<\theta<v(Y|X))=\gamma\text{ for all }(\theta,\varphi)$$

Now this usually just boils down to taking an integral so as long as you can calculate $Y|X$ it should not be too bad.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. you're right, I corrected the mistake in the formula. I've got some problems in understanding your detailed answer....Could you please give me an example? About my formula:you told me, that you think it will work? Could you please answer one more question: How do you know when creating a confidence interval, that there should be Var(p)/n and not only Var(p) ? Is there a rule? I didn't found any literature about the CI I posted bevore,  but I should be able to justify my formula and thoughts....